# SignalR site is not staying in sync when page is open in more than one tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm working through a SignalR demo that displays database info in a list when a button is hit.

My Hub has 2 functions: One to remove DB objects from a list, and one to re-add DB objects to that list.

These functions are performed in my View and perform great when I only have the page open once. But if I open the page in another tab (can be the same browser or a different one), the pages do not stay in sync.
Meaning, when one page's button is hit, the other page is not displaying the data correctly.

Often times one page will do fine, while the other will perform the remove but not the add! It's mind-boggling. They should just be reflections of each other from my understanding.

Has anyone else run into something similar?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's my Hub :

```
[HubName("hubtest")]
public class HubTest : Hub
{
    CmsContext db = new CmsContext();

    public void showdata()
    {
        var f = from x in db.Data
                select x;
        Clients.remove();

        Clients.add(f);
    }
}
```

And here's the javascript in my View for the functions:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    var hubtest = $.connection.hubtest;

    hubtest.remove = function () {
        //clear list of any prior values
        var list = document.getElementById('dataList');
        while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
            list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0])
        }
    };

    hubtest.add = function (data) {
        //populate with updated values
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var element = data[i];
            $('#dataList').append('<li>' + element.Question + '</li>');
        }

    };

    $("#broadcast").click(function () {
        hubtest.showdata();

    });

    // Start the connection
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
</script> 


<input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />
<ul id="dataList">
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you watched the network stream, set breakpoints or put console.log statements in the JavaScript to see if you're getting 1:1 client calls to signals from the server to determine if this really is a SignalR issue? Also, maybe you've simplified the implementation for demo purposes, but it's a little strange (and adds uneeded overhead) to send the remove signal from the server at all in this scenario since the client implementation knows that for every add it wants to clear the list before it repopulates it, so it doesn't need the server to tell it that.

Comment: Hey Drew, thanks for your post. Like you pointed out, there's no reason the remove and add need to be separated. I had them both performing in one function originally, and in an attempt to simplify things and debug I put them in different functions.  I can get it to work if I connect from a console app, so this leads me to believe it must be something in my javascript or SignalR's javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks for your replies. I really appreciate your feedback!
I eventually got it to where my pages are staying in sync when open in multiple tabs by altering how my data is sent to the View.
Where I was performing the for loop in my Javascript to display each piece of data, now I am doing that in my Hub like so:

```
[HubName("hubtest")]
public class HubTest : Hub
{
    CmsContext db = new CmsContext();

    public void showdata()
    {
        Clients.clearlist();
        var faqs = from x in db.Faqs
                select x;
        foreach (Faq faq in faqs)
        {
            Clients.add(faq.Question.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then my Javascript is just appending that FAQ question to the list:

```
$(function () {
    var hubtest = $.connection.hubtest;

    hubtest.clearlist = function () {
        var list = $('#datalist');
        list.empty();
    };

    hubtest.add = function (data) {            
        $('#datalist').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
    };

    $("#broadcast").click(function () {
        hubtest.showdata();
    });

    // Start the connection
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

Sending just a simple string of my data to be printed individually seems to allow my page to stay in sync. 
Before the data I was sending was a list of DB objects and my Javascript was looping through each and adding that object's Question column to the list. Not sure why this was such an issue - especially since it would work on one open tab but not **all** open tabs - but that simple change fixed my site sync issues.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var hubtest = $.connection.hubtest;

        hubtest.add = function (data) {
            //clear the values first.
            var list = $('#dataList');
            list.empty();

            //populate with new values
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var element = data[i];
                list.append('<li>' + element.Question + '</li>');
            }

        };

        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
            hubtest.showdata();

        });

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

And this:

```
[HubName("hubtest")]
public class HubTest : Hub
{
    TestDatabaseEntities db = new TestDatabaseEntities();

    public void showdata()
    {
        var f = from x in db.FAQs
                select x;

        Clients.add(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was just a typo on my part putting the question up. I've updated it.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your update. I changed my code to what you have here, but I still get odd behavior. I'm seeing that if I have my page open in more than one tab, hitting the broadcast button on a page actually performs the add function only on the *other* tab's page - very strange.

Comment: What browser are you using? Did you try using two different type of browser to perform the test?

Comment: I've been testing with IE and Chrome, but doesn't seem to work better in one versus the other.

Comment: This is what i seen so far. If the browser does not have the focus, the sync either lags on one of the screen or does not happen at all. I've been able to see the sync correctly by using IE and Chrome at the same time. Focus one browser and click on the button of the other one.